# Insert Chinese content into an Indesign document? Or with Incopy?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Here's my scenario - I have some business card documents with UK data. Now the client needs a version of the cards for their Chinese department. Can I use Indesign/InCopy to let the client insert the foreign language into my document? PS: Never used data-merge or InCopy before.

Thanks, Henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it would be possible to insert text at least, but I don't honestly know if InCopy allows data merge, but anyway . . .

Personally, I wouldn't let the client do it. They are sure to mess it up in some way, and unless you know Chinese, you won't even know if it's wrong.  To be honest, I wouldn't even let an English speaking client loose on my artwork/layout - but at least I'd be able to tell if they had made a mistake.

Although I haven't done this for Chinese, I once had to do business cards which required a Japanese translation. In fact, it's quite an interesting story which demonstrates one of the pitfalls of letting a client loose on your artwork.

Initially the client gave me the Japanese text, which had been written by his wife who was a native Japanese speaker. Without knowing how to input the text myself, as I don't speak or read Japanese, I sent it off to a professional translation service. They called me to tell me that the Japanese text wasn't correct, and appeared to have several errors. They also explained what was wrong and why it didn't conform to the usual Japanese business card standards. There were problems with the translation of the names, the use of honorifics, and even the layout required some adjustments. Apparently the Japanese have very specific rules and conventions which must be upheld, and take business cards much more seriously than westerners do, so serious in fact that an error on a business card is considered to be tantamount to a cultural faux-pas.

Anyway, I added the text given to me by the translator and followed their recommendations to the letter, and sent the proofs off to the client. The client's wife complained it had been changed (a slightly awkward moment), but I stuck to my guns and told them I had it checked over by a professional translation service since I wasn't able to read Japanese or input the text myself. I also sent them the translation service's explanation of what was wrong with the original copy.

In the end the client approved it, and the business cards were printed. You can imagine the scenario if the client had been able to type the text themselves, and I had just gone ahead with the print job. Sure, it would have been the clients own fault, but then I'd probably have felt under obligation to offer a reprint at a discount rate.

**TL;DR** Be very careful about letting your client do anything!

Comment: Wow, thanks for sharing that story and the advice! I thought the process would be do-able since it’s “just” a business card - but I do see the pitfalls now  I asked the client to send the Chinese text in Word and I’ll take it from there... thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

InCopy is collaborative, while Data Merge is just an InDesign feature that doesn't sync automatically between different users.

InCopy could work, assuming they have a running license of InCopy on their end.

Data Merge not very likely to work for this, unless you expect them to run InDesign inhouse and understand a Data Merge workflow.

Since these are just business cards, so not hundreds of pages of text content, you could potentially attempt to typeset the chinese cards yourself. A client is not very likely to be willing to learn a new — and quite complex — tool, for a simple task.